# How to migrate exsiting sqlite table to ROOM Db which have data types like VCHAR, TIMESTAMP?

Tags: android, sqlite, database-migration, android-room, sqldatatypes

In my old sqlite table I have these Column 
 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,api_response_json TEXT, api_req TEXT,post_params TEXT,req_type VARCHAR,timestamp TIMESTAMP)

Now I am trying to migrate it to Room DB like this:-

static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {

```
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    // Create the new table
        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE users_new (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,api_response_json TEXT, api_req TEXT,post_params TEXT,req_type VARCHAR,timestamp TIMESTAMP)");
    // Copy the data
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users_new (id,api_response_json, api_req,post_params,req_type,timestamp) "
                + "SELECT id,api_response_json, api_req,post_params, req_type,timestamp "
                + "FROM old_Table_name");
    // Remove the old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE old_Table_name");
    // Change the table name to the correct one
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users_new RENAME TO old_Table_name");}
};
```

I am getting an error Migration didn't properly handle

Expected:
 TableInfo{name='api_data', columns={timestamp=Column{name='timestamp', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, req_type=Column{name='req_type', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, post_params=Column{name='post_params', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, api_response_json=Column{name='api_response_json', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, api_req=Column{name='api_req', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Found:
    TableInfo{name='api_data', columns={timestamp=Column{name='timestamp', type='TIMESTAMP', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, req_type=Column{name='req_type', type='VARCHAR', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, post_params=Column{name='post_params', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, api_response_json=Column{name='api_response_json', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, api_req=Column{name='api_req', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

There is problem in  TIMESTAMP and  VARCHAR .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a problem in TIMESTAMP and VARCHAR
you should change it to:

```
    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create the new table
        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE users_new (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,api_response_json TEXT, api_req TEXT,post_params TEXT,req_type TEXT,timestamp TEXT)");
        // Copy the data
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users_new (id,api_response_json, api_req,post_params,req_type,timestamp) "
                + "SELECT id,api_response_json, api_req,post_params, req_type,timestamp "
                + "FROM old_Table_name");
        // Remove the old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE old_Table_name");
        // Change the table name to the correct one
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users_new RENAME TO old_Table_name");}
    };
```

the answer was inside your migration error